# Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15
A problem occurred root project 'android'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.

Solve the error in my flutter project which is linked with the firebase
